# Question on Proof involving direct products and $\pi$-complements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

All groups $G$ are finite, for $N \unlhd G$ we set $\overline{G} := G/N$ and for some $U\le G$ we write $\overline U = UN/N$. Also for a set $\pi$ of primes we denote by $O_{\pi}(G)$ the largets normal $\pi$-subgroup in $G$.

**Lemma:** Fix a set $\pi$ of primes and a group $N$, and consider a collection of subgroups $N_q \unlhd N$, where $q$ runs over some set of primes not in $\pi$ and $N = \prod_q N_q$. Assume for each prime $q$ that $N_q$ is a $(\pi \cup \{ q \})$-group. Then $N$ contains a nilpotent $\pi$-complement and all $\pi$-complements in $N$ are conjugate. Also, if $|\pi| = 1$, then $N$ is solvable.

**Proof:** First, note that $|\prod_{r\ne q} N_r|$ divides $\prod_{r\ne q} |N_r|$, which is not divisble by $q$. Then $N_q \cap \prod_{q \ne r} N_r$ is a normal $\pi$-subgroup of $N$, and it follows that the group $\overline N = N / O_{\pi}(N)$ is the direct product of the subgroups $\overline N_q$. Since each direct factor $\overline N_q$ of $\overline N$ has a nilpotent $\pi$-complement (its Sylow $q$-subgroup), it follows that the direct product $\overline N$ also has a nilpotent $\pi$-complement, and furthermore, since the $\pi$-complements in each factor are conjugate, it follows easily that the same is true for $\overline N$.
Now let $\overline H$ be a nilpotent $\pi$-complement of $\overline N$, where $H \subseteq O_{\pi}(N)$. Applying the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem to $H$, we see that $H$ has a unique conjugacy class of $\pi$-complements, and these are nilpotent $\pi$-complements in $N$. Also, since all $\pi$-complements in $\overline N$ are conjugate to $\overline H$ and all $\pi$-complements in $H$ are conjugate, it follows that all $\pi$-complements in $N$ are conjugate, as required.
Finally, if $\pi = \{ p \}$, then $N_q$ is a $\{p,q\}$-group, so $N_q$ is solvable by Burnside's $p^a q^b$-theorem. It follows that $N = \prod N_q$ is solvable, and the proof is complete. $\square$

I have some questions regarding this proof:

1) $\overline N = N / O_{\pi}(N)$ is the direct product of the subgroups $\overline N_q$.

I know the result that if $G$ is a product of normal subgroups $N_1, \ldots, N_n$, and 
$$
 Z_i := N_i \cap \prod_{i\ne j} N_j
$$
then
$$
 G / \bigcap_{i=1}^n Z_i \cong N_1 / Z_1 \times \ldots \times N_n / Z_n.
$$
So by numbering the set of primes $q_1, \ldots, q_k$ and setting $Z_q := N_q \cap \prod_{q\ne r} N_r$ this yields here
$$
 N / \bigcap_q Z_q \cong N_{q_1} / Z_{q_1} \times \ldots \times N_{q_1} / Z_{q_k}.
$$
Also $\bigcap_q Z_q$ is a normal $\pi$-group in $N$, so by definition $\bigcap_q Z_q \le O_{\pi}(N)$. Applying one of the isomorphism theorems we have
$$
 \left( N / \bigcap_q Z_q \right) / \left( O_{\pi}(N) / \bigcap_q Z_q \right) \cong G / O_{\pi}(N) 
$$
But here I do not see that this yields a decomposition as a direct product? (For this maybe $O_{\pi}(N) / \bigcap_q Z_q$ has to be direct, which would be if $O_{\pi}(N)$ is direct, but why should $O_{\pi}(N)$ be a direct product?)

2) My second question regards the application of the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem.

Is it applied to $O_{\pi}(G)$? So that we have a $\pi$-complement $K$ with $O_{\pi}(G) = HK$? But why should the orders of $H$ and its index in $O_{\pi}(G)$ be coprime?
Or is it applied to $H$ and $N$, but same questions, why should the order of $H$ and the index $|N : H|$ be coprime?

Further the conclusions about the conjugates I do not understand? Thanks for any explanations!

Comment: You seem to be trying to overcomplicate everything. The result that you know in Question 1 is just being applied directly to the subgroups $\overline{N}_q$ of $\overline{N}$, to prove that $\overline{N}$ is the direct product of the $\overline{N}_q$. In Question 2, the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem is being applied to $H$ to show that the normal $\pi$-subgroup $O_\pi(N)$ of $H$ has a complement (which is the required nilpotent $\pi$-complement) and that all such complements are conjugate.

Comment: Sry I do not see it, when I set $Z_i := \overline{N_q} \cap \prod_{r \ne q} \overline N_r$ I just get $$\overline N / \bigcap_q Z_q \cong \overline N_{q_1} / Z_{q_1} \times \cdots \times \overline N_{q_n} / Z_{q_n}.$$ What has this to do with $N / O_{\pi}(G)$? And for my Question 2, why are the order of $O_{\pi}(N)$ and $|O_{\pi}(N) : H|$ coprime? Which is necessary for the application of Schur-Zassenhaus?

Comment: If you replaced each $N_q$ by $N_qO_{\pi}(N)$ then the hypotheses concerning $N_q$ would still hold. So you can assume that $O_\pi(N) \le N_q$ for each $q$. Now the fact that $N_q \cap \prod_{q \ne r} N_r$ is a normal $\pi$-subgroup of $N$ implies immediately that $Z_i=1$. For your second queastion, just note that $H/O_\pi(N)$ is a $\pi'$-group.